# Running a node js code for 24 hours for a month

Tags: node.js

I want to use a code in node js to download json file every 1 hour from a website
But I want it to run for 24 hours for a month
The problem is that I can't trust my device to be running all this time

So my question is what is the best way to perform this task? 
I thought of having a server, but I don't know what to search about, does this task has a name?

Comment: You can use a free server service like Heroku. You can use Heroku Scheduler to run your app every hour and some MongoDB plugin to use as database

Comment: If you don't need to run it all the time, consider something like [Amazon Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html).

Comment: Search for free tier VPS, like AWS or GCP, they suggest free private server for a year; Heroku suspends inactive free tiers but easier to kick off for beginner

Comment: Thanks, Heroku Scheduler with MongoDB plugin worked with me

Answer (score 0):

I think i get you right, the best alternative is to use a server and run a cron-job. the following links can help [enter link description here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/nodejs-cron-jobs-by-examples)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to perform this task is to have a cron job scheduled which downloads the file on an interval of 1 hour. You can use the [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) module and schedule your task like this

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('60 * * * *', () => {
  console.log('running every hour');
});
```

After doing this, you can deploy your code to either [heroku](https://heroku.com) or aws. Heroku is free and easy to setup where as AWS is also free (requires credit card to be added) and is scalable and reliable.

To run a node process in background you can use [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)